# 'Autoplay' on video is not working after refreshing page

Tags: html, css, controls, html5-video, autoplay

I want to add a video that plays by itself and loops, without showing controls. When I add 'controls' to my code, the controls show and the video plays just fine. When I change 'controls' to 'autoplay' and refresh the testing page, the video doesn't play. Here is the code:

```
<video src="./images/Kusko Enterprise Catering Services - Google Chrome 2021-10-03 16-30-57_Trim.mp4" class="kusko_catering_video" autoplay></video>
```

Please could I get help on trying to figure out my mistake?

Answer (score 14):

If you have put the `autoplay` option in element. It will not play on refresh unless you put muted too. This is a special case in browsers which allows to prevent the video to be played out loud in case of just refresh.

so change your element to:

```
<video id="video-field" src="files/video" loop autoplay muted></video>
```

and for angular as someone asked in the comments.

```
<video [muted]="'muted'" loop autoplay [src]="videoSource"></video>
```

Comment: adding muted the angular way [muted]="'muted'" was is the only thing missing for me to make this works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```html
        <video src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/h264.mov" autoplay loop></video>
```

Your code seems good, you have to just add loop attribute for continuous play. I think the problem is in your source.

Comment: Hey! For some reason, this doesn't work as well. it behaves just like when I run your code snippet. I also tried changing my source to yours, but it didn't play

Comment: @MaameYaaTwumasi  Drop jsfiddle link of your code.

Comment: @MaameYaaTwumasi So I can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: this is a link for when I use 'controls': https://codepen.io/maame-yaa/pen/jOwgzBQ and this is a link for when I use 'autoplay loop':https://codepen.io/maame-yaa/pen/KKqOoWb. I used your video source

Comment: I'm experiencing same issue with an Angular app, only works first time when navigating site using menu links etc... but when the pages is refreshed it doesn't auto play no more . Has anyone found out why?

Comment: @JulianoVargas I have added the answer for angular.

Comment: @tech_geek that's intriguing, thanks. I haven't checked it yet but I'll test and let know.

Answer (score -1):

You have to have first interaction on your page before that your player plays.